# pgs4a: Using Webbrowser module?

Tags: android, python, browser, pygame

I am having extreme difficulty trying to figure out how to do this.
Ok, so I would like to monetize an android game that I am working on, so I thought I could just put ads in it, but according to extensive research, (pgs4a is not very well documented) this requires a decent knowledge of java, which I don't have. So I thought I could just create an adf.ly link to my website, and open that in android's browser using python's webbrowser module. But when I call webbrowser.open("example.com") nothing happens, and then the game crashes later on.

What am I doing wrong? It states in the docs that webbrowser should work, any pgs4a experts please help me out, here is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randrange,choice
from math import trunc
import webbrowser
try:
    import android
except ImportError:
    android = None
pygame.init()
if android:
    android.init()
    android.map_key(android.KEYCODE_BACK, pygame.K_ESCAPE)
    import android.mixer as mixer
else:
    import pygame.mixer as mixer
    pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=500)
passsnd=mixer.Sound('pass.wav')
splatsnd=mixer.Sound('splat.wav')
scor=0
font=pygame.font.Font(None,45)
def main():
    scoredraw=font.render('Score: '+str(scor), 0, (255,255,255))
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((480,640))
    px=64
    py=240
    yspeed=0
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    bird=pygame.image.load('bird.png').convert()
    bird.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
    bloodspr=pygame.image.load('blood.png').convert()
    bloodspr.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
    run=1
    mode=1
    endtime='alive'
    class Obstacle(object):
        def __init__(self,x):
            top=randrange(50,300)
            self.rect=pygame.Rect(x,0,64,top)
            self.rectt=pygame.Rect(x,top+160,64,480)
            self.dead=0
            self.gameover=0
        def update(self):
            if self.gameover==0:
                self.rect.right-=3
                self.rectt.right-=3
            if self.dead==0 and self.rect.centerx<px:
                global scor
                global scoredraw
                passsnd.play()
                scor+=1
                scoredraw=font.render('Score: '+str(scor), 0, (255,255,255))
                self.dead=1
            if self.rect.right<0:
                obs.remove(self)
                obs.append(Obstacle(640))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), self.rect, 0)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), self.rectt, 0)
    class BloodPart(object):
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.direction=choice([[0,0],[-randrange(5,30),randrange(5,30)],[randrange(5,30),randrange(5,30)],[randrange(5,30),-randrange(5,30)],[-randrange(5,30),-randrange(5,30)]])
            self.x=x
            self.y=trunc(y)
        def update(self):
            if self.y<592:
                self.x+=self.direction[0]
                self.y+=self.direction[1]
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (self.x,self.y), 3)
                self.direction[1]+=3
                if self.y>590:
                    splatsnd.play()
            else:
                screen.blit(bloodspr,(self.x,605))
    obs=[Obstacle(640)]
    go=0
    pdead=0
    playerrect=pygame.Rect(px-16,py-16,32,32)
    blood=[]
    #+++++++++++++++HERE IS THE ERROR++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    webbrowser.open('facebook.com')
    while go==0:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        words=font.render('Tap to Begin',1,(255,255,255))
        if android:
            if android.check_pause():
                android.wait_for_resume()
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type==KEYUP:
                if e.key==K_ESCAPE:
                    run=0
                    go=1
            if e.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if e.button==1:
                    go=1
        screen.blit(words, (165,250))
        pygame.display.flip()
    while run==1:
        if android:
            if android.check_pause():
                android.wait_for_resume()
        if mode==1:
            screen.fill((0,15,185))
            for o in obs:
                o.update()
                if o.rect.colliderect(playerrect) or o.rectt.colliderect(playerrect):
                    o.gameover=1
                    if pdead==0:
                        while len(blood)<15:
                            blood.append(BloodPart(px,py))
                    pdead=1
            for e in pygame.event.get():
                if e.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if pdead==0:
                        yspeed=-12
                if e.type==QUIT:
                    run=0
                if e.type==KEYUP:
                    if e.key==K_ESCAPE:
                        run=0
            if yspeed<18:
                yspeed+=0.9
            py+=yspeed
            if py>592:
                py=592
                pdead=1
                if len(blood)<15:
                    blood.append(BloodPart(px,py))
                for o in obs:
                    o.gameover=1
                if endtime=='alive':
                    endtime=82
            if py<0:
                py+=14
            playerrect=pygame.Rect(px-16,py-16,32,32)
            screen.blit(bird,(px-16,py-16))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (94,64,0), (0,640,480,-32), 0)
            for b in blood:
                b.update()
            screen.blit(scoredraw, (0,0))
            clock.tick(70)
            if endtime is not 'alive':
                endtime-=1
            if endtime==0:
                mode=2
            pygame.display.update()
        else:
            screen.fill((0,0,0))
            words=font.render('Score: '+str(scor), 0, (255,0,0))
            words2=font.render('Tap to Retry',0,(255,255,255))
            screen.blit(words, (180,250))
            screen.blit(words2,(150,320))
            for e in pygame.event.get():
                if e.type==QUIT:
                    run=0
                if e.type==KEYUP:
                    if e.key==K_ESCAPE:
                        run=0
                if e.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    mode=1
                    px=64
                    py=240
                    yspeed=0
                    go=0
                    bird=pygame.image.load('bird.png').convert()
                    bird.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
                    bloodspr=pygame.image.load('blood.png').convert()
                    bloodspr.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
                    run=1
                    mode=1
                    endtime='alive'
                    obs=[Obstacle(640)]
                    pdead=0
                    playerrect=pygame.Rect(px-16,py-16,32,32)
                    blood=[]
                    global scor
                    global scoredraw
                    scor=0
                    scoredraw=font.render('Score: '+str(scor), 0, (255,255,255))
            pygame.display.update()
main()
```

Things I have tried:

```
using open_new()
enabling INTERNET in the config
using different urls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I fixed this one quite quickly.

As a last hope I tried entering a full url: `open('http://google.com')` and it worked like a charm.

So for anyone else wondering, a full url is required!